# Aspire Acer V3-571G-9686: Wireless Issues

Tags: wireless, internet, aspire

I've had the computer for around 4 months, so it's still relatively new. The core of the issue is that every so often I'll be booted off my wireless. Sometimes the wireless continues to say connected but the net isn't working, sometimes it switches to limited, and sometimes it just boots me completely off and I try to reconnect only to run into issue number one (says "connected", but nothing is happening). Sometimes this happens almost non-stop every 5-10 minutes for a few hours; sometimes it doesn't happen for days at a time. I haven't noticed any trends in terms of my location, the time of day, the amount of items connected to the router, etc.

I initially thought the issue was connected to our wireless because a few devices in the house were having different but seemingly related problems (playing online video games on wireless with random spiking lag and a smart tv that downright refused to stream as it should). We recently upgraded our router to fix these issues. All the other devices are fine now, running smooth as butter, while my issue remains exactly the same.

Any ideas or further information I can provide that would be helpful?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a hardware problem of the network adapter (qualcomm atheros) in that and other ACER models.

I have the same model and looking on the internet found a simple solution to this issue, though I don't know why it works.

Here it is:

Open the lid on the bottom of your notebook (there are two screws). Inside you'll see the wifi card with a white and a black cable attached to it (the antennas). Gently unplug the black cable, it's not sealed, so you can plug it back in anytime.

That's it! Now just close the lid leaving the black cable unplugged and try your wifi.

You should experience no more problems.